Is a smoothing capacitor only useful when the trace has impedance
Under conditions where maybe a capacitor is used maybe when perhaps there's a high impedance power supply and the source would cause current surges, maybe a subwoofer to a car battery that can't deal with current surges. In my current understanding, a capacitor would only be useful if the power line from the battery and sub has some impedance which is causing the power drop and placing the cap near the sub would help. But other than that, I can't understand how a capacitor would help the battery. I understand a capacitor can deliver charge, but simultaneously would the battery not be feedi current to the cap and the load to bring back up to the batteries voltage? Thanks

"Is a smoothing capacitor only useful when the trace has impedance?" How would a trace not have impedance?

@MathKeepsMeBusy Asin more of an ideal case or very short traces

Smoothing capacitors are only useful if the trace has enough impedance to cause a voltage drop at the load, and only really for switching loads.
If there is too much inductance in the trace/conductor and a load switches on (like thousands of transistors in a CPU) then you'll get a drop. The capacitor filters and provides current until the current can 'catch up' from the inductance of the conductor from the source.
In the battery case, it will be delivering current but the conductor will prevent the current from getting to the load instantanously, so you need a cap. The cap must be placed near the load. Another option is to decrease the inductance of the conductor. If you put the capacitor by the battery and still have inductance in series with the load, it won't help filter.

Non-switching but sensitive analog loads can also require bypass capacitors. It's not unusual to get weird behaviour out of an op amp missing its bypass cap. Linear regulators are also prone to oscillation without sufficient output bypassing, but that's a bit of a different matter.

Yes, I guess the better term is changing loads.
